# How do I insert results from an SQL query into a Pug template with Express and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, pug

I am working on writing a simple web application which will initially display a list of bus route numbers and names when landing on the page. I am using MySQL with Express and Pug. Here is the server-side code along with the first few results from `console.log`:

```
const express = require('express');
const pug = require('pug');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('mysql');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'coolio',
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: 'routes'
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const routesQuery = "SELECT route, route_name FROM routes";
  let routeObj = {};
  connection.query(routesQuery, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      routeObj.route = results[i].route;
      routeObj.routeName = results[i].route_name;
      console.log(routeObj);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Listening..");
});


Listening..
{ route: 1, routeName: 'Metric/South Congress' }
{ route: 2, routeName: 'Rosewood' }
{ route: 3, routeName: 'Burnet/Manchaca' }
{ route: 4, routeName: 'Montopolis' }
{ route: 5, routeName: 'Woodrow/South 5th' }
{ route: 6, routeName: 'East 12th' }
```

So far I have been unable to figure out how to get the results displaying in `console.log` to display on the page when it is loaded.

Putting `res.render('index', routeObj);` where the `console.log` is throws multiple errors regarding headers (`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`). However I can't access the object's information outside of the for-loop; trying to render my index page with the routeObj object just displays a blank page.

Here is the Pug HTML:

```
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='stylesheets/normalize.css' )
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='stylesheets/style.css' )
  body
    div.container
      div#test
        p=routeObj
```

I seem to get closer when I included `res.render('index', {routeObj});` after the for-loop-- the page then at least displays `[object Object]`.

How can I get the data that appears in my `console.log` to show up inside of my template?

Answer (score 0):

That is because Pug calls `Object`'s `toString()` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Which returns `[object Object]`.

Your options are:

1. Override or implement your own `toString()` function to output what you want.
2. Access the specific properties on the `routeObj` object.

Example of 2:

```
const routeObj = {
  name: 'foo'
}

...

html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='stylesheets/normalize.css' )
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='stylesheets/style.css' )
  body
    div.container
      div#test
        p=routeObj.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the results using `for x in y` or any other looping method in the pug file

Here is a an example

```
app.get('/details', function(req, res) {

connection.query('SELECT * From `employees`', function (error, results, fields) {
 if (error) throw error;
 console.log('The solution is: ', results);

  res.render('details', {
    title: 'Details - Pug ExpressJS NodeJS Tutorial',
    employees: results
  });

});

});
```

In pug file

```
for employee in employees
   tr.odd(role='row')
       td #{employee.name}
       td #{employee.position}
       td #{employee.office}
       td.dt-body-right.sorting_1 #{employee.age}
```